# How does ADT differ from the Chorus (modulation) effect?

Tags: effects, flanger

What are the main differences between Automatic double tracking (like what the beatles used on vocals) and the Chorus (modulation) effect?

Answer (score 4):

Automatic double tracking, or artificial double tracking adds a delayed copy of the signal.

Chorus adds a delayed copy of the signal whose pitch is also modulated with a low frequency oscillator.

Comment: Yes, though actually it is the _delay time_ that's being modulated, and the pitch modulates [as a consequence of that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect).

Answer (score 1):

The George Martin version of ADT simply used a delayed signal.

In a modern take on ADT though, it is also possible to pitch-shift the signal by a few cents, instead of or as well as adding a delay.  This makes the double-tracked copy less obviously the same, giving a more realistic effect.  As an improved version of this, adding *two* signals with one pitch-shifted up by a few cents and the second pitch-shifted down by the same amount avoids the pitch "centre" changing.  This is clearly different from delay and modulation effects.

[This SoundOnSound article](https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/double-tracking-vocals) discusses the options available for ADT, including pitch-shifting.